# Как снять бекап БД с помощью PowerShell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Есть виртуальный сервер "ИМЯ СЕРВЕРА", на нём крутится база "ИМЯ БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ". Задача: снять бекап на диске, на самом сервере. Нашел фрагмент в интернетах, но не пойму где здесь логиниться и подозреваю, что проблема именно в этом. PS 4.0, MS SQL Server 2012

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | out-null
$server = New-Object("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") "ИМЯ СЕРВЕРА"
$database = $server.Databases["ИМЯ БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ"]
$timestamp = Get-Date -format yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss
$backup = New-Object("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup")
$backup.Action = "Database"
$backup.BackupSetDescription = "Комментарий к резервной копии"
$backup.BackupSetName = "Название резервной копии (хорошо видно при восстановлении)"
$backup.Database = "ИМЯ БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ"
$backup.MediaDescription = "Disk"
$backup.Devices.AddDevice("ПУТЬ К ПАПКЕ С РЕЗЕРВНЫМИ КОПИЯМИ" + $timestamp + ".bak", "File")
$backup.SqlBackup($server)
```

На что PS ругается при выполнении последней строки

> Исключение при вызове "SqlBackup" с "1" аргументами: "Не удалось
>   выполнить действие "Резервное копирование" для следующего объекта:
>   "Сервер", "254-SERV". " D:\Папка\бекапчик.ps1:15 знак:1
>   + $backup.SqlBackup($server)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.
Не могу писать в комментах, отпишусь тут.
Была такая ошибка, когда указывал в "ПУТЬ К ПАПКЕ С РЕЗЕРВНЫМИ КОПИЯМИ" сетевую шару или папку, на которую нет прав.
Если пытаетесь положить на шару - сделайте бэкап на локал, а потом скопируйте.

Ещё вариант - посмотреть windows events. Можно там поискать эвенты типа BackupDiskFile::CreateMedia, там будет написана причина ошибки.

Comment: Нет, к сожалению, это не срабатывает. Пробовал и на самом сервере запускать скрипт с локальным диском - не спасло.

Comment: Тогда нужно больше информации. Что пишется в windows events?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo');           
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc');           
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO');           
# Requiered for SQL Server 2008 (SMO 10.0).           
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMOExtended');           
$Server = "server\instance";     # SQL Server Instance.           
$Dest = "F:\backup\";    # Backup path     
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $Server;           
# If missing set default backup directory.           
If ($Dest -eq "")           
{ $Dest = $server.Settings.BackupDirectory + "\" };           
Write-Output ("Started at: " + (Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss));           
# Full-backup for every database           
foreach ($db in $srv.Databases)           
{           
    If($db.Name -ne "tempdb")  # Non need to backup TempDB           
    {           
        $timestamp = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss;           
        $backup = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup");           
        $backup.Action = "Database";           
        $backup.Database = $db.Name;           
        $backup.Devices.AddDevice($Dest + $db.Name + "_full_" + $timestamp + ".bak", "File");           
        $backup.BackupSetDescription = "Full backup of " + $db.Name + " " + $timestamp;           
        $backup.Incremental = 0;           
        # Starting full backup process.           
        $backup.SqlBackup($srv);    
        # For db with recovery mode <> simple: Log backup.           
        If ($db.RecoveryModel -ne 3)           
        {           
            $timestamp = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss;           
            $backup = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup");           
            $backup.Action = "Log";           
            $backup.Database = $db.Name;           
            $backup.Devices.AddDevice($Dest + $db.Name + "_log_" + $timestamp + ".trn", "File");           
            $backup.BackupSetDescription = "Log backup of " + $db.Name + " " + $timestamp;           
            #Specify that the log must be truncated after the backup is complete.           
            $backup.LogTruncation = "Truncate";
            # Starting log backup process           
            $backup.SqlBackup($srv);           
        };           
    };           
};           
Write-Output ("Finished at: " + (Get-Date -format  yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss));
```

Answer (score -2):

Я проще делаю. Мне хватает. :)

```
#   Шринкуем базу. Надо, и точка.
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$Server_Target" -ConnectionTimeout 300 -QueryTimeout 600 -AbortOnError -Query "DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(N'$DB_TargetName_Etalon')"

#   Бэкапим базу эталона.
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$Server_Target" -ConnectionTimeout 300 -QueryTimeout 600 -AbortOnError -Query "BACKUP DATABASE `"$DB_TargetName_Etalon`" TO DISK = '$Path_BackUpDir\$DB_TargetName_Etalon.[$BuildNumber].bak'"
```

Comment: Invoke-Sqlcmd : Конвейерная обработка была остановлена.
строка:1 знак:1
+ Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "254-SV-OSIS-02" -ConnectionTimeout 300 -QueryTime ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], PipelineStoppedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExectionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Invoke-Sqlcmd : Cannot open backup device 'E:\FIAS_test.bak'. Operating system error 5(failed to retrieve text for th
is error. Reason: 15105).

Comment: BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
строка:1 знак:1
+ Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "254-SV-OSIS-02" -ConnectionTimeout 300 -QueryTime ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Comment: Вот так ругается на вторую команду. Первая выполнилась без проблем.

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов
Так пишет же прав нету. Не факт, что учетка, под которой выполняется скрипт права имеет. Об этом тоже надо помнить. И не сетевой диск ли это случаем? Он подключается для пользака, а ен для машины в целом.

Comment: Зачем делать SHRINKDATABASE перед бэкапом?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, чтобы размер уменьшить. Бэкапы у нас хранятся долго. Борюсь за каждый мегабайт т.к. рукоблудство отказывается выделать бабки на железо. Только экономить или покупать самому.

Comment: @JGooLaaR намного эффективнее делать разностные бэкапы

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Такой взрослый дядя, а что такое бэкапы шрёдингера не знаешь. :) Когда у тебя разок вот один в цепочке бэкап "не откроется" - вспомни меня. Тока несильно. Не хочу икать долго.

Comment: @JGooLaaR а нефиг длинные цепочки делать. Если делать каждый второй бэкап разностным - это не сильно скажется на надежности, но будет при этом намного эффективнее шринков.

Comment: @JGooLaaR кстати, вы же знаете что бэкапы можно проверять? Или для этого тоже места нет? :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, знаю. сразу после создания допустим живой, когда-нибудь потом, когда понадобится - неожиданно нет. и знаете почему самым надежным пистолетом считается револьвер? так вот. именно по этому без дифф бэкапов и дополнительных действий с ними. :)